# UITableView Segue To View Controller NOT Working

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, segue

In my app I have a table view that lists out friend's names and when you click on the names in the table view it is supposed to perform a segue into another view controller that stores this friends information. Although I can click on the rows, it is not performing the segue into the friend information view controller. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks in advance! :)

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var friends = ["A","B","C","D"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

self.tableView.dataSource = self
self.tableView.dataSource = self

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.friends.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    let friend = self.friends[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.text = friend
    return cell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("detailSegue", sender: nil)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let listVC = segue.destinationViewController as! FriendDetailViewController
}
```

Comment: Show your storyboard with selection of segue.

Comment: You may want to check that your segue has the correct identifier as string identifiers are case sensitive and there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code. Also, check that the segue is from the Main View Controller to the Detail View Controller not from the prototype cell to the Detail ViewController.

Comment: I see u have `self.tableView.dataSource = self`
 twice but no `delegate` is assigned. Which means `tableView:didSelectRwoAtIndexPath` is not called. replace one of these `self.tableView.dataSource = self` with `self.tableView.delegate = self`, and u should be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should assign in the tableView delegate to the view controller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after 

    loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self

}
```

And of course add this :

```
class ViewController : ... , UITableViewDelegate
```